# A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type 'BitmapHandle' failed to properly release the handle with value

Tags: c#, wpf

When closuing a SplashScreen in a WPF application, I receive the following error:

```
Message: A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type 'BitmapHandle' failed to properly release the handle with value 0xD0052B9B. This usually indicates that the handle was released incorrectly via another means (such as extracting the handle using DangerousGetHandle and closing it directly or building another SafeHandle around it.)
ReleaseHandleFailed was detected
```

Comment: Related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85eak4a0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems a bug on the framework as mention in this page.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720719/releasehandlefailed-thrown-by-mda-when-using-the-splash-screen-feature-of-wpf

I was receive this exception in debug mode, when having Debug/Exception "ALL" enabled in VS 2010.

In order to get rid of this Exception I had to reset to default Debug/Exception in VS 2010.

Comment: @stephenbayer url looks ok now

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable the ReleaseHandleFailed Exception under **Managed Debugging Assistants** in *Debug -> Exceptions* to get rid off the compiler warning.